# 'Resource.Dimension' does not contain a definition for

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

**Visual Studio 2017 intellisense** underline all dimension resources in my cs code with the error: *`Resource.Dimension` does not contain a definition for...*

Intellisense offer me only standard dimensions properties.

File with my dimensions is placed in `Resources\values\dimens.xml`.

This file has following content:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <dimen name="main_text_item_size">17dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

All others resources are okay and I can work with them without any problem.

> My configuration: VS 2017, jdk1.8.0_172
>
> References:  Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat v27.0.2,
>   Xamarin.Android.Support v27.0.2

Comment: So you can run the app without a problem but intellisense can't find it?

Comment: Have you tried opening the Resource.Designer, removing a couple of lines and rebuilding the project?

Comment: Tom Esendam - yes, I can run application without a problem

Comment: hichame.yessou - Yes, I tried what you suggest to me, but problem persists

Answer (score 1):

The one solution that I found is copying my Resource.Designer.cs file to ../obj/debug/designtime location where I overwrite original file.

And now everything is OK and I do not have any underlined resource properties in my cs files.

Answer (score 1):

> 'Resource.Dimension' does not contain a definition for

Xamarin not correctly processing `dimen` resource items when parsing
the actual resources. It will be fixed in the newer version of Xamarin.

Bug: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/1784

GitHub PR fix: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/pull/1786

**Workaround:**

Please refer to **@Sobansky**'s answer.

Comment: I didn't know that is a bug in Xamarin. It is useful information for me.

Comment: @Sobansky, thanks for your reply. I will update this answer once it been fixed. :)